# Trying to inject @Applicationscoped CDI bean into EJB bean fails with ContextNotActiveException

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, websphere, cdi, ear

I am trying to use an `@ApplicationScoped` CDI bean in my EAR app on Websphere 8.5.5, but I am failing to do so.

My structure:

- app.ear

  - ejb.jar

    - MyEJB
  - lib/

    - lib.jar

      - MyLib

MyLib is the CDI bean:

```
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;

@ApplicationScoped
public class MyLib {

...

}
```

And I want to inject it into the stateless bean MyEJB:

```
@Stateless
public class MyEJB implements MyEJBLocal {

@Inject
private MyLib myLib;

...

}
```

I am using @ApplicationScoped, since this seems to be the recommended way to create a CDI managed Singleton.

*Note:* I am not using any WARs, I don't have a web layer.

Now when the EJB bean gets instantiated, I get the following exception:

```
 javax.enterprise.context.ContextNotActiveException: WebBeans context with scope type annotation @ApplicationScoped does not exist within current thread
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I inject a Singleton CDI bean into the EJB?

Comment: Webshere has too many bugs when it comes to CDI..  see this : http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI19074

Comment: If you are not using web layer then I would suggest to `@Singleton` for managed singletons, it will be much cleaner than introducing CDI in EJB layer.

Comment: Also do you have `beans.xml` file in your `META-INF` folder in ejb module?

Comment: @EduardoYáñezParareda Websphere 8.5.5.3

Comment: @Gas Yes the `beans.xml` is in every jar (ejb, lib); "Normal" Dependend beans get injected without problem. Which `@Singleton` do you mean? The `ejb` or the `javax.inject`?

Comment: @ares Indeed the CDI implementation in Websphere is not without problems, I have experienced that myself. Once I am able to update to 8.5.5.4 I will try out that fix you mentioned

Comment: I was thinking about `javax.ejb.Singleton`.

Comment: @Gas Since the singleton is in a library jar and not in an EJB module, I'm not sure if that would work? `javax.ejb.Singleton` defines a EJB singleton bean with transaction management etc. That's actually not really what I want, I just want it to be a POJO.

Comment: Oh, yes, I didn't noticed it is in lib.